# Problema: doble click a menu responsivo con angular para que funcione

Tags: typescript, sass, jmenubar, angular13

Hola que tal comunidad soy nuevo por aquí y tengo la siguiente duda

Estoy haciendo un menu responsivo con el ts de angular la funcion basica que siempre se usa en un script para un menu responsivo el problema que tengo es que para que agarre el menu despliegue u oculte dicho menu hay que darle doble click o doble toque con el dedo para que me agarre, alguno de ustedes tiene alguna idea de porque pasa esto anexo el codigo:

html:[image: html]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TS:
[image: ts]

CSS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este menu lo he implementado ya varias veces con html  js y css sin angular y si funciona pero al momento de usar angular no quiere funcionar

Answer (score -1):

Ya pude solucionar el problema.

Tras leer la documentación de angular medí cuenta de algo no es necesario escuchar el evento con el addEventListener ya que de ello se encarga el event binding por lo que me salia ese problema dejo la solucion por si le sirve a alguien
Cambie de esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías de añadir tu código insertandolo, en vez de poniendo imágenes. Por favor, edita la pregunta y pega el código